# Why random forest always give 1.0 prediction score?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm trying to test the prediction score of the following classifiers:

```
- random forest
- k neighbors
- svm
- naïve bayes
```

I'm not using feature selection or feature scaling (no preprocessing at all).

I'm using a train-test split as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)
```

I tested several datasets (from `sklearn`):

```
- load_iris
- load_breast_cancer
- load_wine
```

In all those 3, random forest always gave perfect prediction (test accuracy 1.0).

I tried to create random samples for classification:

```
make_classification(flip_y=0.3, weights = [0.65, 0.35], n_features=40, n_redundant=4, n_informative=36,n_classes=2,n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=50000)
```

and again random forest gave perfect prediction on the test set (accuracy 1.0).

All the other classifiers gave good performance on the test set (0.8-0.97) but not perfect (1.0) as random forest.

- What am I missing ?
- Does random forest really outperforms all other classifiers in a perfect way ?

Comment: We're talking for training prediction or test prediction?

Comment: test prediction: score(X_test, y_test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the perfect accuracy score of 1.0, we have to keep in mind that all these 3 datasets are nowadays considered as actually toy ones, and the same probably holds true for the artificial data generated by scikit-learn's `make_classification`.

That said, it is true that RF is considered a *very* powerful classification algorithm. There is even a relatively recent (2014) paper, titled [Do we Need Hundreds of Classifiers to Solve Real World Classification Problems?](http://jmlr.org/papers/v15/delgado14a.html), which concluded (quoting from the abstract, emphasis in the original):

> We evaluate **179 classifiers** arising from **17 families** (discriminant analysis, Bayesian, neural networks, support vector machines, decision trees, rule-based classifiers, boosting, bagging, stacking, random forests and other ensembles, generalized linear models, nearest-neighbors, partial least squares and principal component regression, logistic and multinomial regression, multiple adaptive regression splines and other methods) [...] We use **121 data sets**, which represent the **whole UCI** data base [...] **The classifiers most likely to be the bests are the random forest** (RF) versions

Although there has been some criticism of the paper, mainly because it [did not include boosted trees](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/11/11/some-thoughts-on-do-we-need-hundreds-of-classifiers-to-solve-real-world-classification-problems) (but not only for that, see also [Are Random Forests Truly the Best Classifiers?](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v17/15-374.html)), truth is that, in the area of "traditional", pre-deep learning classification at least, there already was the saying *when in doubt, try RF*, which the first paper mentioned above came to reinforce.